# jquery popup window wont fade in on page load

Tags: jquery, html

hi everyone im trying to make a popup window fade in when the page loads. Im using jquery but its not fading in after a short amount of time like it should.Instead its already there when the page loads for some reason. Can someone please explain what im doing wrong ? thanks

```
$(function() {
          $('#modal').css('display','block');
      $('.modal-bg').fadeIn(1000);
});

    $('#close').click(function(){
          $('.modal-bg').fadeOut();
          $('#modal').fadeOut();
      return false;
    });
```

html

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <span class="button">Sign In</span>
<div class="modal-bg">
  <div id="modal">
    <span>Sign In<a href="#close" id="close">&#215;</a></span>
    <form>
      <input id="username" name="username" type="textbox" placeholder="Username" required>
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      <a id="forgot-link" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
      <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably just need to hide it initially with some css - display:none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the modal to be hidden by default:

```
<div class="modal-bg" style="display: none">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $('#modal').css('display','block');
      $('.modal-bg').fadeIn(1000);
});

$('#close').click(function(){
      $('.modal-bg').fadeOut();
      $('#modal').fadeOut();
});
```

What $(window).load does is to wait for everything to download before running the function.

Also make sure the modal is hidden in CSS by default.

Hope it helps!